# VBA pass cell value to Print dialogue box

Tags: vba, excel

This is the Sub that I have built so far:

```
Sub Grab_Screencap()

    'Open URL
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate _
            Worksheets("Queue").Range("A3").Value
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "^p", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "{UP}", True
        SendKeys "{UP}", True
        SendKeys "~", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "~", True

    End With

End Sub
```

I am sure there are much better ways to do it, but I am still on the kiddie side of the pool.

This takes a URL that I have in a spreadsheets, and then opens IE, navigates to that page, opens the Print dialogue box, selects XPS Document Writer, navigates to the pathway field, and then highlights the value.

Now I want to pass a base directory, and a file name from a cell, something like

```
"C:\users\user1\desktop\" & Worksheets("Queue").Range("A5").Value
```

Tinkering around but cant find any existing documentation that lines up with what I'm trying to do that I can comprehend.

Comment: What I do to ascertain how to do new things is to record a macro and then look to see what that is doing.

Comment: Which would work if Macro recording extended outside of Excel. Maybe im missing a setting, but once I leave Excel, the macro stops recording. Anyhoo, I figured out a workaround. Just clever extended use of SendKeys.

Comment: Are you trying to Print the content of the external (non-Excel Workbook) file?

Comment: I am trying to make a spreadsheet where I enter a craigslist URLs, job titles, and contact email addresses, and excel automatically prints a copy of the listing to a set directory and emails a customized coverletter with resume attached. This bit was trying to figure out how to get the print-to-file of the listing, so im trying to print the content of an IE browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, im sure this isn't nearly the most elegant way to achieve the task, but this is what I was able to write that does what I want it to do:

```
Sub Grab_Screencap()

Dim i As Integer
i = 3

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))

    'Copy Screencap Name
    Sheets("Queue").Cells(i, 6).Copy

    'Open URL

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate _
            Worksheets("Queue").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "^p", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "{UP}", True
        SendKeys "{UP}", True
        SendKeys "~", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "~", True
        SendKeys "C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\Job Listings\"
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "^v", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        SendKeys "%s", True
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
        IE.Quit

    End With

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

The 101 lesson was that SendKeys can send an entire string, not just a single key. I didnt need to merge the file name with the pathway. I just needed to drop the pathway, tab back to file name, and drop the file name, which I could copy before opening IE.

I think there is a way to do this task just by opening the print dialogue and activating print to file, but I have not tried to figure that out yet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the content of the external file (for example, C:\Temp\TestFile.txt) from Excel VBA macro you can use `ShellExecute()` function as shown below.

First, insert the VBA `Module` (e.g. `Module1`) and place the following declarations and `Sub` into that `Module1`:

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
   "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation _
   As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters _
   As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd _
   As Long) As Long
Public Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

Public Sub ShellExecuteSample()
    'shown as example: it will open the text file C:\Temp\TestFile.txt
    OpenFile = ShellExecute(hwnd, "open", "C:\Temp\TestFile.txt", "", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL)

    'this will print the content of the text file C:\Temp\TestFile.txt
    PrintFile = ShellExecute(hwnd, "print", "C:\Temp\TestFile.txt", "", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
End Sub
```

When called, this `Sub ShellExecuteSample()` will print the content and (optionally) open the text file: `C:\Temp\TestFile.txt`. Pertinent to your case, it could be the file specified by your string:

```
"C:\users\user1\desktop\" & Worksheets("Queue").Range("A5").Value
```

Apparently, you do not need a `PrintDialog` to complete this task.

Hope this may help.